# The error page of meta.stackoverflow.com asks us to report the error on meta.stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, meta, 500-server-error

The [error page of meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/error) says:

> It's not strictly necessary, but if
>   you'd like to give us additional
>   information about this error, do so at
>   our feedback site,
>   http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

If the website is not working it would be fairly difficult. I realize that the error may appear only on some pages, such as maybe the `/user/` pages, but there is a good chance the error will appear on every page or on the `/ask` page.

Also the error message explains what meta is (`our feedback site`), which the user already knows since they are already there.

I suggest to change it to:

> It's not strictly necessary, but if
>   you'd like to give us additional
>   information about this error, do so by emailing team@stackoverflow.com

This would be for the meta error page only.

Comment: Seems to me like this is an infinite recursive loop leading to an eventual stack overflow, thus I believe this should be closed as `[status-bydesign]`

Comment: +1 for the suggested change - if meta's down it's a really bad UX decision to direct people to meta!

Comment: Simple, on the meta site it should add "when it is back up." to the message.

Answer (score -1):

Unlikely we will make this change, since it would affect one site in the entire network.

Presumably the user is smart enough to figure out what to do here?

Comment: Presumption was at its peak in the 18th century. You sir, are sickly of much too much presumption. Plus, everybody loves email!

Comment: Well, meta is already different in many ways, such as the "bugs" tab, etc. Why can't it be different in this case too?

Comment: If you don't mention the `team@` address in the error page, you can't expect the user to know it.